# iText.Layout.Document disregards space taken by merged pdf

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

I create pdfs containing text, images and existing pdfs. Existing pdfs are added via merging them into the pdf. The problem is if first a pdf is added and then an image the iText.Layout.Document does not account for the space taken by the merged pdf and instead adds the image following the "Document Title" paragraph (see example).

This creates out of order images and sometimes even overlapping of images and merged pdfs. I need correct order and no overlapping, how can I solve this?

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new PdfWriter(stream).SetSmartMode(true))
using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer))
using (var doc = new Document(pdf))
{
    doc.Add(new Paragraph("Document Title")

    //pdf is added via merging, results in pdf being on the second page which is ok
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(somePdfByteArray))
    using (var reader = new PdfReader(ms))
    using (var pdfdoc = new PdfDocument(reader))
    {
        PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);
        merger.Merge(pdfdoc, 1, pdfdoc.GetNumberOfPages());
    }
    //then image is added but it is added BEFORE the pdf which is the problem
    doc.Add(new Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(someImageByteArray)));
}
```

Comment: How about creating a separate pdf (probably only in memory) with only the content you want to append after the merged document and merging that after the other document? (The problem can be solved more easily but this is a solution you could have come up with considering the code you show.)

Comment: This is a solution to consider but I guess it's very inefficient as that would mean creating intermediate pfds many times as I repeatedly have to add text, pdf, text, pdf, ... to the result pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the approach suggested in the comments (creating in memory documents for merging/appending) is not possible due to performance issues and you don't mind the content being added on a new page in the document you could try this approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
    addContent(new Paragraph("Document Title"), pdfDocument);
    mergePdf(new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC)), pdfDocument);
    addContent(new Div().add(new Image(ImageDataFactory.create("path_to_image"))), pdfDocument);
    pdfDocument.close();
}

public static void mergePdf(PdfDocument in, PdfDocument pdfDocument) throws Exception {
    in.copyPagesTo(1, in.getNumberOfPages(), pdfDocument, new PdfPageFormCopier());
}

public static void addContent(IBlockElement content, PdfDocument pdfDocument) throws Exception {
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
    pdfDocument.addNewPage();
    document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.LAST_PAGE));
    document.add(content);
}
```

*I wrote the code sample in Java but iText for Java and .NET share the exact same codebase, so this shouldn't be an issue.*

In this approach we force iText to add a new page before adding content on the high level Document class. If you want to add images using this approach you will have to wrap them in an IBlockElement for this method to work. The most appropriate element would be the *Div* one.

Regards,
Kevin